# How to record files on a server with minimal access using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post, httppostedfile

How to record files on a server with minimal access using MVC. The next version of the code is not suitable as it will be clogging up the domain.

**Controller code:**

```
var fileFile = Request.Files["p" + prop.Id];
if (fileFile == null) continue;

string pathFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "UploadedFiles";
string filenameFile = Path.GetFileName(fileFile.FileName);

if (filenameFile != null) fileFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(pathFile, filenameFile));
```

***(if it is possible to realize this by putting file to the cache)***

EDITED CODE:

var ordinaryPropertyValue = new Catalog.Core.Entities.OrdinaryPropertyValue();

Environment.CurrentDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");

var fileFile = Request.Files["File" + prop.Id];
if (fileFile == null) continue;

string pathFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

fileFile.SaveAs(pathFile);

ordinaryPropertyValue.Value = pathFile;

instance.SetPropertyValue(prop.Id, ordinaryPropertyValue);

Comment: What is "minimal access"? Are we talking about security here?

Comment: Rather use `string pathFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "UploadedFiles");`

Comment: yes, minimal access means-security

Comment: but this is not the way to resolve the issue

Comment: You could store them in the temporary directory.  Every user (including ASPNET) should have access to this I think so don't need to assign any permissions. string tempDir = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();

Comment: i have just rewrite my code(You can see it on the top - EDITED CODE:)
BUT I GET : Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Temp' is denied.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the common application data location (this would be better than %TEMP% if you need them to stick around - people have a tendency to clean the %TEMP% folder out from time to time in my experience) - all users should have access to that and then you could just put it in a sub-folder like so:

```
var appDataFolder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
var dir = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(appDataFolder, "My Application"), "UploadedFiles"):

// save your files into dir
```

Here are all the "special folders" in case you see one that you would rather use:  [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)